# Im getting attributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'zipcode' when running this code

Tags: python, api, class

My code:

```
import requests
class weatherapi:
 def __init__(self,api_url,string,zipcode):
    self.api_url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=10502,us&appid=50b55ef1602086c74b71f56c6df14996'
    self.input = string
    self.zipcode = zipcode
 def get(self):
    get_weather = requests.get(self.api_url)
    json_weather = get_weather.json()
 def response(self):
    national = requests.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip='+self.zipcode+',us&appid=50b55ef1602086c74b71f56c6df14996')
    json_national = national.json()
    kelvin = float(national.json['main']['temp'])
    return str(kelvin)

from weatherapi import weatherapi
def main():
    zipcode = input('Please input your zip code ')
    weatherapi.response(zipcode)
```

I get `attributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'zipcode'` when running this code. I have no idea why this is happening, could somebody explain why?

Comment: You did not create an instance of your class.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your posted code, and make sure it's clear what code is in which file. Also please show the complete stack trace for the error, formatted as code.

Comment: Please explain what your code is meant to do.

Answer (score 1):

The function `.response` does not take any arguments aside from the reference to the object ("`self`").

You need to first construct an instance of the class before you can use the `.response()` function. You'll need something like `my_weatherapi = weatherapi('https://www.some.url.com/', 'some_input_string', 90210).

Also, the error code is `AttributeError`, not `tributeError`.

All in all, there are a lot of mistakes in this. I would recommend you go through a Python tutorial first; specifically look into defining classes and using constructors and class functions.